# FrameBuffer size in libgdx

Tags: java, camera, libgdx, framebuffer

I want to use `Framebuffer`s in my little libgdx game.

The game uses `scene2d` and I modify the `Stage`s camera to use a viewport of 50 width and 31 height. Then I set the `SpriteBatch`'s projection matrix to `camera.combined`. Doing this I have a resolution independent game and I can use my own "WorldUnit" instead of using pixels.

But now, if I create a `FrameBuffer`, I have to give it a size. Do i have to give it the size of the cameras viewport or the size of the screen in pixels?

And, when I render things to that `FrameBuffer`, can I render them in `WorldUnits`, meaning rendering at `P(25,16)` is almost in the middle of the game window?

Thanks

Comment: So i use the same values as for normal rendering? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its the `height` and `width` of the frame which should be buffed. So it should be the viewport height and width if you dont do something fanzy with it. (Same as at the Stage for example)

Just do mention dont forget to add the `setSize` of the `FBO` to the resize method of your Scene2D.

Comment: So i use (Pseudocode) `framebuffer = new FrameBuffer(pixmapFormat, camera.viewPort.width, camera.viewPort.height, hasDepth);`? And then can i use the same spritebatch again or do i have to use another one for the frambuffer rendering?

Comment: Yes. but as i said take a look at the example from the shadertutorial. Everything is there what you need to know. At the resize: `fbo = new FrameBuffer(Format.RGBA8888, width, height, false);` Maybe dont use new the whole time but its an example..

Comment: I already saw that tutorial, and i want to do exactly the same (lightmap without box2d lights) but they also use shaders and i wat to do it without shaders. Thanks